FancyHeader Right Header Location
I am trying to move only the text that says "Name:" to the left so that students will be able to right their name. I tried to add \hspace{2in} to my right header, but it did not work. I also tried \fancyheadoffset[R]{2cm}, but it also moved the horizontal rule I have.  I would like to keep the line rule across the page if possible.  Thank you for the help.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=25mm, vmargin={1cm,4.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol,fancyhdr,fullpage,setspace,parskip}

% HEADER AND FOOTER
\pagestyle{fancy}
\headheight 35pt
\lhead{\textbf{Skill Builder:} \big(Topic 2.8 \& 2.9\big)}
\chead{\textbf{}}
\rhead{Name:}
\lfoot{Mr. Bennett}
\cfoot{Flint Hill Upper School}
\rfoot{\small\thepage}
\headsep 1.5em
\begin{document}
Sample questions
\end{document}


Just add \hspace where you need space for the name:

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=25mm, vmargin={1cm,4.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol,fancyhdr,fullpage,setspace,parskip}

% HEADER AND FOOTER
\pagestyle{fancy}
\headheight 35pt
\lhead{\textbf{Skill Builder:} \big(Topic 2.8 \& 2.9\big)}
\chead{\textbf{}}
\rhead{Name:\hspace{4cm}}
\lfoot{Mr. Bennett}
\cfoot{Flint Hill Upper School}
\rfoot{\small\thepage}
\headsep 1.5em
\begin{document}
Sample questions
\end{document}


Hey David, thank you! I had originally tried that and there was no change. Works perfectly.  Not sure what I did wrong. There were no errors in my document either.
